# import packages in petdapp

Tags: dapps, nodejs

I unboxed petdapp and done some editing where I need to import bcrypt-nodejs in app.js and used following steps.

`npm install bcrypt-nodejs --save`

`npm install require --save`

**app.js**

`var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs)`

While executing application it gives an error `Cannot find module bcrypt-nodejs`.

Do I need to specify the path anywhere?

**bs-config.json** is as follows:

```
{
 "server": {
"baseDir": ["./src", "./build/contracts"]
}
}
```

I added **./node_modules** under **"baseDir"** along with folder path **src** and **contract**. It did not resolved the issue.

I tried package **aes256** module and get same error with warning as :

```
[ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'aes256'. '/home/Documents/Dapp/node_modules/aes256/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/aes256` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'aes256';`
```

I tried another method : `import { default as aes } from 'aes256';`. Still same issue.